# Не обновляет время телеграмм бот на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
введите сюда код

import telebot 
import datetime
import random
import pytz
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['time', 'start','ha'])

def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "/time":
        
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, now)
    elif message.text == "/start":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пока в разработке")
    
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, kek)          
            
    else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Я тебя не понимаю.Иди 
работай или отдыхай.")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

При вводе /time всегда показывает одинаковое время.
/time 2021-09-12 22:14:15.919900+03:00
/time 2021-09-12 22:14:15.919900+03:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенеси строчку `now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow'))` внутрь функции. А то у тебя в `now` содержится время запуска бота.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало)